# How do I find relative files in python with ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, python

Basically, I am trying to set the background of ubuntu to a file, and I pretty much need to use relative paths.

I have looked at other people's and tried what they did but it didn't work, it just changes the background to a dark blue colour.

My code: `os.system('gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:../Installer/Assets/BG.png')`

Also, I am using Ubuntu 21.10 and yes, I have added the OS module.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1396172/edit) and add OS information.

Comment: You must find a way to define the relative path. It's not hard. Just ask yourself: Are you using a user's /home dir? Or the PWD? Or something else? And construct your path that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, user535733 I changed the code so it uses PWD to find it.

`os.system('gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:$PWD/Assets/BG.png')`